# Classical Single Pivot QuickSort implementation in Java using Generics

Tags: java, generics, quick-sort

I have coded the following quick sort implementation.
There are few things that still makes this code ugly and redundant.

**1. Handling Arrays of Primitives**
I have to write a separate implementation of QuickSort to handle each of the 7 primitive types. Is there a way, this could be done in a much better way?

**2. Usage of "private static" - nested classes**
Is it okay to model the nested classes that encapsulates the quicksort logic for each variant of the input type as 'private static'. Will there be any other better way to code them yet having them in the same java file.

**3. `Comparator<? super T>`**

In the below snippet,

```
private static <T> int partition(T[] values, int start, int end, Comparator<? super T> comparator) {
            T pivot = values[end];
            int partitionIndex = 0;
            for (int i = 0; i < end; ++i) {
                if (comparator != null) {
                    if (comparator.compare(values[i], pivot) <= 0) {
                        swap(values, i, partitionIndex);
                    }
                }
            }
            // swap the pivot.
            swap(values, partitionIndex, end);
            return partitionIndex;
}
```

Have declared a Comparator whose parameterized type could be just T or it's sub types. Is it okay and conventional to accept a child class comparator to compare
base class types. I borrowed this logic from

```
Arrays.sort(T[], Comparator<? super T>)
```

Just wanted to know the rationale behind specifying '? super T' instead of just T.

**4. `<T extends Comparable<T>>`**

In the below snippet,

```
public static <T extends Comparable<T>> void sort(T[] values) {
            validateInputArray(values);
            quickSort(values, 0, values.length - 1);
}
```

I have tried to make sure at the compile time itself, the array elements
are supposed to be implementing Comparable interface.
Is the above one > is okay or can it be made better.

Here's the complete compilable code of QuickSort.

```
//QuickSort.java

package com.gnanavad.dsa;

import java.util.Comparator;

public class QuickSort {

    // QuickSort API - for arrays of all 7 primitive types
    // in java except boolean.

    public static void sort(byte[] values) {
        QuickSortPrimitives_Byte.sort(values);
    }

    public static void sort(short[] values) {
        QuickSortPrimitives_Short.sort(values);
    }

    public static void sort(int[] values) {
        QuickSortPrimitives_Int.sort(values);
    }

    public static void sort(long[] values) {
        QuickSortPrimitives_Long.sort(values);
    }

    public static void sort(float[] values) {
        QuickSortPrimitives_Float.sort(values);
    }

    public static void sort(double[] values) {
        QuickSortPrimitives_Double.sort(values);
    }

    public static void sort(char[] values) {
        QuickSortPrimitives_Char.sort(values);
    }

    // QuickSort API for arrays of POJOs which doesn't implement Comparable
    // interface.
    // Hence, appropriate Comparator has to be supplied as one of the inputs.
    public static <T> void sort(T[] values, Comparator<? super T> comparator) {
        QuickSortNonPrimitives_ExternalComparator.sort(values, comparator);
    }

    // QuickSort API for arrays of Boxed Types and POJOs that are Comparable.
    public static <T extends Comparable<T>> void sort(T[] values) {
        QuickSortNonPrimitives_ImplicitComparator.sort(values);
    }

    private static void validateInputArray(Object values) {
        if (values == null) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("Input array is null.");
        }
    }

    /*
     * Implementation of QuickSort encapsulated in a class of their own for each
     * variant of input types.
     **/

    // Both the NonPrimitive versions of QuickSort shares the same swap() logic
    // and hence the base class.
    private static abstract class QuickSortNonPrimitives {
        protected static <T> void swap(T[] values, int i, int partitionIndex) {
            T tmp = values[i];
            values[i] = values[partitionIndex];
            values[partitionIndex] = tmp;
        }
    }

    private static class QuickSortNonPrimitives_ImplicitComparator extends QuickSortNonPrimitives {

        public static <T extends Comparable<T>> void sort(T[] values) {
            validateInputArray(values);
            quickSort(values, 0, values.length - 1);
        }

        private static <T extends Comparable<T>> void quickSort(T[] values, int start, int end) {
            if (start < end) {
                int partitionIndex = partition(values, start, end);
                quickSort(values, 0, partitionIndex - 1);
                quickSort(values, partitionIndex + 1, end);
            }
        }

        private static <T extends Comparable<T>> int partition(T[] values, int start, int end) {
            T pivot = values[end];
            int partitionIndex = 0;
            for (int i = 0; i < end; ++i) {
                if (values[i] != null) {
                    if (((Comparable<T>) values[i]).compareTo(pivot) <= 0) {
                        swap(values, i, partitionIndex);
                    }
                }
            }
            // swap the pivot.
            swap(values, partitionIndex, end);
            return partitionIndex;
        }

    }

    private static class QuickSortNonPrimitives_ExternalComparator extends QuickSortNonPrimitives {

        public static <T> void sort(T[] values, Comparator<? super T> comparator) {
            validateInputArray(values);
            quickSort(values, 0, values.length - 1, comparator);
        }

        private static <T> void quickSort(T[] values, int start, int end, Comparator<? super T> comparator) {
            if (start < end) {
                int partitionIndex = partition(values, start, end, comparator);
                quickSort(values, 0, partitionIndex - 1, comparator);
                quickSort(values, partitionIndex + 1, end, comparator);
            }
        }

        private static <T> int partition(T[] values, int start, int end, Comparator<? super T> comparator) {
            T pivot = values[end];
            int partitionIndex = 0;
            for (int i = 0; i < end; ++i) {
                if (comparator != null) {
                    if (comparator.compare(values[i], pivot) <= 0) {
                        swap(values, i, partitionIndex);
                    }
                }
            }
            // swap the pivot.
            swap(values, partitionIndex, end);
            return partitionIndex;
        }

    }

    private static class QuickSortPrimitives_Int {

        public static void sort(int[] values) {
            validateInputArray(values);
            quickSort(values, 0, values.length - 1);
        }

        private static void quickSort(int[] values, int start, int end) {
            if (start < end) {
                int partitionIndex = partition(values, start, end);
                quickSort(values, 0, partitionIndex - 1);
                quickSort(values, partitionIndex + 1, end);
            }
        }

        private static int partition(int[] values, int start, int end) {
            int partitionIndex = 0;
            int pivot = values[end];
            for (int i = 0; i < end; i++) {
                // move the small ones to the left of partitionIndex.
                if (values[i] < pivot) {
                    swap(values, partitionIndex, i);
                    partitionIndex++;
                }
            }
            // swap the pivot.
            swap(values, partitionIndex, end);
            return partitionIndex;
        }

        private static void swap(int[] values, int index1, int index2) {
            int tmp = values[index1];
            values[index1] = values[index2];
            values[index2] = tmp;
        }
    }

    private static class QuickSortPrimitives_Short {

        public static void sort(short[] values) {
            validateInputArray(values);
            quickSort(values, 0, values.length - 1);
        }

        private static void quickSort(short[] values, int start, int end) {
            if (start < end) {
                int partitionIndex = partition(values, start, end);
                quickSort(values, 0, partitionIndex - 1);
                quickSort(values, partitionIndex + 1, end);
            }
        }

        private static int partition(short[] values, int start, int end) {
            int partitionIndex = 0;
            short pivot = values[end];
            for (int i = 0; i < end; i++) {
                // move the small ones to the left of partitionIndex.
                if (values[i] < pivot) {
                    swap(values, partitionIndex, i);
                    partitionIndex++;
                }
            }
            // swap the pivot.
            swap(values, partitionIndex, end);
            return partitionIndex;
        }

        private static void swap(short[] values, int index1, int index2) {
            short tmp = values[index1];
            values[index1] = values[index2];
            values[index2] = tmp;
        }
    }

    private static class QuickSortPrimitives_Float {

        public static void sort(float[] values) {
            validateInputArray(values);
            quickSort(values, 0, values.length - 1);

        }

        private static void quickSort(float[] values, int start, int end) {
            if (start < end) {
                int partitionIndex = partition(values, start, end);
                quickSort(values, 0, partitionIndex - 1);
                quickSort(values, partitionIndex + 1, end);
            }
        }

        private static int partition(float[] values, int start, int end) {
            int partitionIndex = 0;
            float pivot = values[end];
            for (int i = 0; i < end; i++) {
                // move the small ones to the left of partitionIndex.
                if (values[i] < pivot) {
                    swap(values, partitionIndex, i);
                    partitionIndex++;
                }
            }
            // swap the pivot.
            swap(values, partitionIndex, end);
            return partitionIndex;
        }

        private static void swap(float[] values, int index1, int index2) {
            float tmp = values[index1];
            values[index1] = values[index2];
            values[index2] = tmp;
        }
    }

    private static class QuickSortPrimitives_Double {

        public static void sort(double[] values) {
            validateInputArray(values);
            quickSort(values, 0, values.length - 1);

        }

        private static void quickSort(double[] values, int start, int end) {
            if (start < end) {
                int partitionIndex = partition(values, start, end);
                quickSort(values, 0, partitionIndex - 1);
                quickSort(values, partitionIndex + 1, end);
            }
        }

        private static int partition(double[] values, int start, int end) {
            int partitionIndex = 0;
            double pivot = values[end];
            for (int i = 0; i < end; i++) {
                // move the small ones to the left of partitionIndex.
                if (values[i] < pivot) {
                    swap(values, partitionIndex, i);
                    partitionIndex++;
                }
            }
            // swap the pivot.
            swap(values, partitionIndex, end);
            return partitionIndex;
        }

        private static void swap(double[] values, int index1, int index2) {
            double tmp = values[index1];
            values[index1] = values[index2];
            values[index2] = tmp;
        }
    }

    private static class QuickSortPrimitives_Char {

        public static void sort(char[] values) {
            validateInputArray(values);
            quickSort(values, 0, values.length - 1);

        }

        private static void quickSort(char[] values, int start, int end) {
            if (start < end) {
                int partitionIndex = partition(values, start, end);
                quickSort(values, 0, partitionIndex - 1);
                quickSort(values, partitionIndex + 1, end);
            }
        }

        private static int partition(char[] values, int start, int end) {
            int partitionIndex = 0;
            double pivot = values[end];
            for (int i = 0; i < end; i++) {
                // move the small ones to the left of partitionIndex.
                if (values[i] < pivot) {
                    swap(values, partitionIndex, i);
                    partitionIndex++;
                }
            }
            // swap the pivot.
            swap(values, partitionIndex, end);
            return partitionIndex;
        }

        private static void swap(char[] values, int index1, int index2) {
            char tmp = values[index1];
            values[index1] = values[index2];
            values[index2] = tmp;
        }
    }

    private static class QuickSortPrimitives_Byte {

        public static void sort(byte[] values) {
            validateInputArray(values);
            quickSort(values, 0, values.length - 1);

        }

        private static void quickSort(byte[] values, int start, int end) {
            if (start < end) {
                int partitionIndex = partition(values, start, end);
                quickSort(values, 0, partitionIndex - 1);
                quickSort(values, partitionIndex + 1, end);
            }
        }

        private static int partition(byte[] values, int start, int end) {
            int partitionIndex = 0;
            byte pivot = values[end];
            for (int i = 0; i < end; i++) {
                // move the small ones to the left of partitionIndex.
                if (values[i] < pivot) {
                    swap(values, partitionIndex, i);
                    partitionIndex++;
                }
            }
            // swap the pivot.
            swap(values, partitionIndex, end);
            return partitionIndex;
        }

        private static void swap(byte[] values, int index1, int index2) {
            byte tmp = values[index1];
            values[index1] = values[index2];
            values[index2] = tmp;
        }
    }

    private static class QuickSortPrimitives_Long {

        public static void sort(long[] values) {
            validateInputArray(values);
            quickSort(values, 0, values.length - 1);
        }

        private static void quickSort(long[] values, int start, int end) {
            if (start < end) {
                int partitionIndex = partition(values, start, end);
                quickSort(values, 0, partitionIndex - 1);
                quickSort(values, partitionIndex + 1, end);
            }
        }

        private static int partition(long[] values, int start, int end) {
            int partitionIndex = 0;
            double pivot = values[end];
            for (int i = 0; i < end; i++) {
                // move the small ones to the left of partitionIndex.
                if (values[i] < pivot) {
                    swap(values, partitionIndex, i);
                    partitionIndex++;
                }
            }
            // swap the pivot.
            swap(values, partitionIndex, end);
            return partitionIndex;
        }

        private static void swap(long[] values, int index1, int index2) {
            long tmp = values[index1];
            values[index1] = values[index2];
            values[index2] = tmp;
        }
    }

}
```